# python install package from python

Tags: python, easy-install

How can I install/check/upgrade a python package from python ? I don't want to run easy_install in the console, I'm trying to make a wrapper to easy_install.

From cli I'm able to do this:

```
easy_install somelib
pip install somelib
```

I want to install packages from python. Ex:

```
try:
    import somelib
except ImportError:
    myFunctionInstall("somelib")
```

Comment: See http://whathaveyoutried.com/; other than that, I'd start with [`pip`](https://github.com/pypa/pip) as a base, it should be easier to drive than `easy_install`.

Comment: I've completed the post with some sample code of what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

You generally do *not* want to do this. Provide proper dependencies in your `setup.py` file instead, and let tools like `pip`, `easy_install` or `zc.buildout` do the dependency work for you. People deploying the code need to be able to control *where* dependencies are installed, for example, to keep conflicting versions separate.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
import os

myFunctionInstall(module):
    os.system("pip install " + module)

try:
    import somelib
except ImportError:
    myFunctionInstall("somelib")
```

You must have pip installed in your system. Hope it helps :)